# unable to find an exact match of CDP version 116

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

Console log:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Sep 01, 2023 1:10:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 115
```

Code:

[image]

Comment: I have downloaded chrome version of 116

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: No errors there, only warnings

Comment: Yes definitely I am remember that thing at next time  @seenukarthi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using selenium `v4.11.0`, refer the below screenshot. Selenium supports only up to `CDP 115`. This is the reason for the WARN which you are seeing in your console. Having said that, it is just a warning and not error, it will not stop your code from running.

[image]

Source : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG